# How do I preview this data on JQuery accordion before submitting to the database?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

We are using jQuery accordion to process our records.

The first accordion called Builds contains two dropdownlistboxes and an input textbox.

The code below works well in populating the dropdownlistboxes.

getBuilds() populates the buildingID dropdownlistbox

The second dropdownlistbox gets populated based on selection from buildingID dropdownlist.

User manually enters data into the input textbox.

Then there is the second accordion called Previews.

As the name suggests, once user clicks on the Preview accordion, the value of the two dropdownlistboxes and the input textbox should display on this screen.

If data is correct, user clicks the submit button to the database.

If not, user can make changes before submitting.

How do I get the values from the code below to display on the Preview accordion?

I can handle the rest with your generous assistance on the preview bit.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Please see code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getdates();

        $('#datesID').change(function() {
            gettimers( $(this).val() );
        });
    });
```

Comment: there is no accordion code shown...please create a demo in jsfiddle.net. Also have no idea what you want displayed from the form data

Comment: @charlietfl, my sincere apology Charlie, I thought I needed an example of how to send stuff to preview to some page.

Here is fiddle. Please let me know I didn't do it right.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Cgu4/3/

Basically, the Preview page wouldn't need any input text boxes or dropdowns; just a listing of choices and data from Buildings according.

Comment: can't put script tag in script section of fiddle....set scripts on left and add jquery ui css into `external resources`. Now you are mentioning another page.... is this occuring on 2 pages? Very confusing

Comment: @charlietfl, No, sorry to confuse you. This is just one page.

I believe I indicated on my initial post that the first accordion called Builds has the two dropdowns and an input textbox. That one is fine.

In order words, if I click on Preview accordion page, I would like to see the same data entered on Builds accordion before submitting to the db.
What I need help on is how to put preview the information entered on Builds accordion in Preview accordion.

Comment: please create simplified ***working*** demo without ajax in code of just the builds and previews sections. Since that is the part you seem to need help with. As far as I can see the ajx is irrelevant at this time...you just want to know how to preiew...is that not correct?

Comment: you will also need html with ID's for the preview elements rather than blobs of text and `<br>`

Comment: @charlietfl, I made the changes. Hopefully, that's what you wanted to see.

It really doesn't matter if they are textboxes or not. How this is done is all I ask for and I can do the rest. 

Thank you sir for your assistance.

Comment: try this...please in future at least make demos work  (note how scripts are included) http://jsfiddle.net/8Cgu4/9/

Comment: @charlietfl, hi Charlie, thanks so much for your assistance. It is much appreciated. 

There is a problem here. First, your js is creating building and floor records. This is what I was afraid of. The JS I posted was already creating the records by populating the dropdowns. What would have been nice is if your code was to be integrated with the existing js. This way, if user selects a record from any of the dropdowns, the Preview accordion is updated. Your script is working with the 5 records it is creating.

Comment: if it isn't fairly obvious that you need to remove `fixDemo()` you really shouldn't be coding. In order to provide you with something that works, and since you didn't provide any hard coded `<option>` tags, I had to improvise. There is no way your existing ajax would work...there was no source provided

Comment: @charlietfl, well what can I say!

I provided the code I used for populating two dropdowns and I provided the source code for those as well as simple source code for the Preview page.

My hope was that whoever is kind enough to assist me would make changes to the js and get it to work just like the fixdemo script you provided.

I have nothing but THANKS to you for even taking your valuable time to try even though the code isn't much of help.

I would have been more than happy to provide hardcoded options. I just didn't know you wanted one.

Comment: Kenny...the ajax you had had no source, so was of no value in demo unless you created source for the requests. You asked for how to display previews...it's up to you to now integrate with your other code. Combining them should not be difficult...take what I gave you and add it to your code. Expecting people here to write full apps for you is not the purpose of this site